# Categorizing Hospital Admittance Data in Excel or R

Tags: r, excel, categorization

I have patient data that looks like this:

```
ID    DATE          DUR    
82    29/08/2014    10.32
82    29/08/2014    0.32
82    12/09/2014    13.35
82    12/09/2014    0.16
82    12/09/2014    0.24
82    12/09/2014    0.31
82    22/12/2014    100.39
82    22/12/2014    0.1
219   31/11/2012    -300.32
219   31/11/2012    0.23
219   12/01/2013    80.20
219   12/01/2013    0.20
```

In the first column is a patient ID, In the second there is a date and time (time is visually missing but is in there) and the third is just the duration difference (which I have been using to determine different admittance of patients). Each different row is a check up on the patient but they may have come here at a later date (not with in the same time frame).

Basically what I want to do is to be able to categorize each patients number so that when they admit a second time there id becomes "82a" and third time "82b" and so on. It wouldn't have to be alphabetic it could be any such indicator.  Sometimes there can be patients with as many as 50 different admissions (separate occasion admissions). So after this I want to have it look something like:

```
ID    DATE          DUR
82    29/08/2014    10.32    
82    29/08/2014    0.32
82a   12/09/2014    13.35
82a   12/09/2014    0.16
82a   12/09/2014    0.24
82a   12/09/2014    0.31
82b   22/12/2014    100.39
82b   22/12/2014    0.1
219   31/11/2012    -300.32
219   31/11/2012    0.23
219a  12/01/2013    80.20
219a  12/01/2013    0.20
```

I have been working in Excel for the time being and at first had used

```
=IF(AND(ABS(C3)>1,A3=A2),1,0)
```

Just to allow to indicate when an ID is repeated on a new admission date, then I did this again to indicate the 3rd admission and began drawing out columns for 4th,5th,6th and planned on merging them. This is simply not an efficient solution, especially with a large data set. I am familiar with R and think that might be a better way for manipulation but I am just stuck with how to do this for the entire data set and to continually add a new "indicator" every time the same patient is admitted again. I am not even sure exactly how to tell the computer what to do with pseudo. Perhaps something like this

```
Pseudo-Code
-> Run through ID Column
-> IF Dur is > 1 (it will always be > 1 for a new admission) 
ANDIF ID already exists above with DUR > 1 = a,  or if DUR > 1 TWICE  for
same ID = b, or if DUR > THREE TIMES = c, and so on....
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Your data is suspect; November only has 30 days.

Comment: Indeed - this field of data here isn't actually a copy and paste job from my data. I just wrote it out in the format that my data is in for visualization sake.

Comment: I've also managed to solve my problem simply in Excel by using `IF(NOT(A3=A2),1,IF(AND(C3=1,A3=A2),D2+1,D2))` where C column holds my indicator variable for each new admission

Answer (score 0):

In R, you have a lot of options. Your data has issues, however; since November only has 30 days, converting the `DATE` column to an actual date format will introduce `NA`s. (You could, of course, just leave it as character, but date formats are easier to work with.)

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%    # parse date data
    group_by(ID) %>%                                   # group data by ID
    mutate(visit = as.integer(factor(DATE)))           # make an integer factor of DATE 
# Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#       ID       DATE     DUR visit
#    (int)     (date)   (dbl) (int)
# 1     82 2014-08-29   10.32     1
# 2     82 2014-08-29    0.32     1
# 3     82 2014-09-12   13.35     2
# 4     82 2014-09-12    0.16     2
# 5     82 2014-09-12    0.24     2
# 6     82 2014-09-12    0.31     2
# 7     82 2014-12-22  100.39     3
# 8     82 2014-12-22    0.10     3
# 9    219       <NA> -300.32    NA
# 10   219       <NA>    0.23    NA
# 11   219 2013-01-12   80.20     1
# 12   219 2013-01-12    0.20     1
```

---

Base R has a lot of options, including `ave` and `tapply`, but to keep it simple so you can see what happens step-by-step in a split-apply-combine model, `split` by grouping variable, `lapply` across the list, and use `do.call(rbind` to reassemble:

```
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, '%d/%m/%Y')
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), 
                            function(x){data.frame(x, 
                                                   visit = as.integer(factor(x$DATE)))}))
rownames(df) <- NULL    # delete useless rownames
df
#     ID       DATE     DUR visit
# 1   82 2014-08-29   10.32     1
# 2   82 2014-08-29    0.32     1
# 3   82 2014-09-12   13.35     2
# 4   82 2014-09-12    0.16     2
# 5   82 2014-09-12    0.24     2
# 6   82 2014-09-12    0.31     2
# 7   82 2014-12-22  100.39     3
# 8   82 2014-12-22    0.10     3
# 9  219       <NA> -300.32    NA
# 10 219       <NA>    0.23    NA
# 11 219 2013-01-12   80.20     1
# 12 219 2013-01-12    0.20     1
```